# Subgroups weaker conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

We know that given $G$ group and $H\subseteq G$, the first condition for $H$ being a subgroup is that $e_G \in H$ (for $e_G$ neutral element in $G$), the other two conditions are the closure under product and closure of inverse element.

So I want to know whether it is really neccesary to ask $e_G \in H$, or can we deduce it by the other two conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the condition that $1\in H$. It follows from the other two: $1=aa^{-1}$ assuming of course that $H$ is not empty.

The empty set is closed under products and inverses but is not a subgroup.

Comment: Ok, so we are asking $e_G \in H$ to be secure that $H\neq ∅$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks JCAA, nice

Answer (score 1):

It not very necesary, in the other hand, the others two conditions, can be put like a $ab^{-1} \in H$.
therefore the theorem say $H\subseteq G$ $H\neq \emptyset$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $e_{G}\in H$, $ab^{-1} \in H$. Notice that you can see that $ab^{-1} \in H$ implies that $ab\in H \forall a,b \in H$ and $a^{-1}\in H$ given $a\in H$.
And you can put $aa^{-1}=e_{G}$

Comment: Note that $H$ can be equal to $G$. The notation $\subset$ is ambiguous on this point.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks Brien!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test) states that if $H\subseteq G$ is nonempty such that for all $a,b\in H$, we have $ab^{-1}\in H$, then $H\le G$. It does not specify which elements are needed to show that $H\neq\varnothing$; typically, though, $e_G$ is easiest.

If $G$ is finite, then it is enough to show that $\varnothing\neq H\subseteq G$ is closed under the group operation in order for $H\le G$.

---

It is necessary to have $H\neq\varnothing$, since $\varnothing \not\le G$; it has no identity element!

Comment: You are right, your comment was very helpfull!

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful, @AldoSosaBlack :)